# How to find a recurring pattern into a list of numbers?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-recognition, nyquist

I need a way to find pattern in list of values. In particular every second I get a value in a range (ex. 1-3), and I want to find recurring pattern from this value list.

If i plot this values into an x,y system i'd get something like a Nyquist–Shannon sampling. It could be very interesting to work on this.

I could also plot these values and work on visual pattern recognition (neural networks...).

input:

```
instant  value


1          1
2          2
3          3
4          1
5          2
6          3
7          1
```

output->1,2,3

What could be the best way to proceed ?

Comment: If this is not as trivial as you have listed in your example then I would think of feeding the sampled data to an FFT algorithm and analyze the returned frequency components.

Comment: Could you be more specific ?